# startssl cert e-mail to receive verification code

Tags: certificates

I'd like to configure AD FS in my lab and one of the pre-requisites is to have "a publicly trusted certificate for SSL Server authentication" so far so good. I came across https://www.startssl.com and it looks like I would have to receive an e-mail first with the verification code. Why's that ? Do I have to be the explicit owner of a domain to a get a publicly recognized certificate ?

thanks
Adam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I have to be the explicit owner of a domain to a get a publicly recognized certificate ?

Of course. It would be very bad if somebody could get a publicly trusted certificate for a domain owned by somebody else since this certificate could then be used in a man in the middle attack. The whole point of the server certificate is that it identifies the real server for the domain and not some man in the middle claiming to be the domain.